# Не работает связь 1 к 1 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, entity-framework-core

Сделал бд с 2 таблицами `User` и `Profile`. Они должны быть связаны 1 к 1, но почему-то поле `Profile` в таблице `User` всегда `null`. И наоборот у таблицы `Profile` поле `User` всегда `null`. Вот код:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Unknown";
    public int Age { get; set; } = 0;
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
User user1 = new User { UserName = model.UserName, Password = model.Password };
db.Users.Add(user1);
db.Profiles.Add(new UserProfile { User = user1});
db.SaveChanges();
```

Пытаюсь вытащить данные вот так:

```
User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserName == username);
if (user != null)
{
    if (User.Identity.Name == user.UserName)
    {
        return View("MyProfile", user.Profile);
    }
    return View("Profile", user.Profile);
}
return View("Profile");
```

Если посмотреть данные то все заполняется правильно, как я понял. Вот скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SQL Код таблицы `Profile`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profiles] (
    [Id]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Age]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserId] INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Profiles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Profiles_Users_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Profiles_UserId]
    ON [dbo].[Profiles]([UserId] ASC);
```

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.1.php кажется вы не туда воткнули аттрибут `ForeignKey`

Comment: `public int UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }` Не сработало

Comment: `User user = db.Users.Include(u=>u.Profile).FirstOrDefault(p => p.UserName == username);` ?